# how to use java code in struts html tags

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, taglib, struts-1

I used **struts-html.tld** tag library

```
<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="/WEB-INF/taglibs/struts-html.tld" %>
```

I want to use java code like object.getName() inside value attribute but its not allowing to use

```
<td><html:text property="name" value=<% object.getName() %> /> </td>
```

I want to assign value dynamically by program How can i assign value to struts tag?

Answer (score 0):

The point of the `html:text` tag (and all the other form tags) is to populate the text field with the value the corresponding property has in the form bean. Make your action set the form bean's name property to what you want, and simply use

```
<html:text property="name" />
```

Scriptlets should be avoided anyway in a well-designed MVC app. Iy you had to get some value from an object, use the JSP EL:

```
${object.name}
```

Comment: @e-zinc and @ JB Nizet
Now i want to assign session attribute like
<td><html:text property="name" value=<%= session.getAttribute(id) %> /> </td>
How to print

Comment: Do that in the Struts action, by getting the attribute from the session, and assigning it to the form bean's name property : `myForm.setName((String) session.getAttribute("id"));`

Comment: @ e-zinc and @JB Nizet I want to add conditon statement in value also for checking like <html:text property="name" value="<%= if(flag){ objbusinessDetails.getName()} %>" /> what should i do .it is only for expression is it right?

Comment: I told you, twice already, to assign the value to the name property of the form bean, from the struts action. That makes it three times. Are you reading the answer?

Comment: Sorry @JB Nizet but i am not using beam form & dont want to use that

Comment: Then don't use Struts. That's how Struts work: it's an MVC framework, and its tags expect to find their value in a form bean. That's like buying a brand new car and asking how to drive it without using the pedals and the steering wheel.

Comment: Then read the Struts user guide (http://struts.apache.org/1.x/userGuide/index.html) and the servlet/JSP tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html)